# PHP - My own counter - Trouble

Tags: php, counter

I made my own custom counter, to count people that connect on my website. This is the code :

```
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT date, id FROM views WHERE ip='$ip' ORDER BY date DESC",$mydb);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0){
    $id_ip=mysql_result($query,0,'id');
    $limit_time=strtotime("-20 minutes");
    $current_time=strtotime(mysql_result($query,0,'date'));
} else {
    $limit_time=$date;
    $current_time=0;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['nickname'])) {
    $user=$_SESSION['nickname'];
} else {
    $user="gtw@visitor";
}

if($current_time<$limit_time) {         
    $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO views (ip, user, date) VALUES ('$ip', '$user', '$date')", $mydb);
} else {
    if($user!="gtw@visitor") {
        $update=mysql_query("UPDATE views SET date='$date', user='$user' WHERE id='$id_ip'",$mydb);
    } else {
        $update=mysql_query("UPDATE views SET date='$date' WHERE id='$id_ip'",$mydb);
    }
}
```

Problem is this : if I connect to the website with the same IP (so, the same computer for example) with 2 browser, which I'll log with 2 different username, It just count as a single visitor. Any suggestion to better this situation?

Maybe add for each connection an HASH generated from BROWSER AGENT? Dunno...

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use Google Analytics (http://www.google.com/analytics/) or similar?  You're reinventing the wheel pretty hard here...

Comment: You're worried someone will juke your stats by using two browsers?

Comment: As Brad said, no point reinventing the wheel here. Just use Google Analytics or a similar service. These may be less reliable overall, but provide a lot more functionality.

Comment: Free version of Google Analytics is limited to 5 million pageviews a month if you don't have active Google AdWords account.

Comment: But can I add my own code on my website trought Google Analytics? I mean : I'd like to print how many users visit my website, who is the last user connected... and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, many clients can share the same public IP address.

Google gets around this problem by using a cookie.  This isn't foolproof, but is about the best you can do.  You can use this method to also track the sequence of pages visited on your site.

Really though, you should just use an off-the-shelf analytics package, such as [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Comment: In fact, by using cookie, this couldn't work. An user could disable session/cookie from the browsers... I think User Agent of the browsers is better...no?

Comment: Absolutely not.  You've never heard of the same version of the browser being installed on two machines?  Far less reliable than cookies I'm afraid.  Yes, of course someone can disable cookies.  This is rare these days though.

Comment: @Brad But if we use cookie to count unique hits how can we control cookie size? If we set cookie duration to be one day, one user may view hundreds of pages. By the way, I don't find any cookie from StackOverflow that indicates which page i've visited, but they do show 'Viewed xx times' on question pages. I think we could ask meta stack overflow about this count question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie and check to see if exists before you add to the counter, though that might give you some other issues. You might want to look at how the wordpress stat counter is implemented, or, alternatively, go for google analytics (unless you really want to roll your own :))

Comment: Where can I see the Wordpress counter? :)

Comment: The plugin can be downloaded [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/) - the actual storage is done on external servers, but you may still be able to find something to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user agent string to the views table so that each visit would consist of the tuple (IP, Date, User agent). This would help count visits from the same IP on different browsers as two different visits.

You can get the user agent string using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].